# Basis of $(\mathbb{R}^2)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $dx,dy$ be the standard basis of the dual space $(\mathbb{R}^2)^*$.

Let $T(x,y)=(T_1(x,y),T_2(x,y))$ be a diffeomorphism.

Is $(dT_1,dT_2)$ in turn a basis? Why?

How do we express differentials in that basis?

Comment: What do you know about $T$'s Jacobian matrix?